# AWS Athena why size of a single row or its columns cannot exceed 32 MB error in select * from tableName but not in where condition

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-athena

When i run `select * from tableName`, I get below error in AWS Athena:

**Your query has the following error(s):
[ErrorCategory:USER_ERROR, ErrorCode:DATA_ERROR], Detail:Size of a single row or its columns cannot exceed 32 MB**

When i run `select * from tableName where col1 is not null`. I can see all the data.

My concern is: why `select * from tableName` without where condition is giving me error on AWS Athena while *with where condition is not giving me error*.

What happens in backend against both the query. I am reading parquet data from S3 and querying on the AWS Athena.

Please share your input.

Comment: Maybe it's another column that is too wide, but `col1` is null on those particular rows. For example, selecting it where `col1 is null` would likely hit the rows that have columns that are too big.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein has a point. It would be great if you could share the data types for each column in your table to confirm that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem indeed. Moreover, I checked that condition column shouldn't influence anyway.

`SELECT * FROM tableName;` fails with error **Size of a single row or its columns cannot exceed 32 MB**

While `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE colName < 30 * 1024 * 1024;` doesn't fail.

The most interesting is that result of `SELECT count(*) FROM tableName;` equals result of `SELECT count(*) FROM tableName WHERE colName < 30 * 1024 * 1024;`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30203581)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error with one of the Athena tables. Adding a filter clause in select query was working and without a where clause it was throwing the same error "size of a single row or its columns cannot exceed 32 MB".

AWS support team confirmed this as one of the limitations with Athena Version 2.0 and recommended to use Version 3.0. For me, just upgrading the Athena version worked and this error got resolved.

Comment: I'm using Athena engine v3 and I get the same error. Question if there is a way to skip ignore this error and skip the record without failing the query